# Error in Batch run when using tasklet of spring batch in JpaPagingItemReader

Tags: hibernate, spring-data, spring-batch, spring-data-jpa, jta

We are facing the below error while running the batch job using tasklet in entity manager of spring batch in JpaPagingItemReader

Can someone help please..

> 2016-04-08 15:04:04,441 CASTXN-545651522545055 ERROR [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] o.s.b.c.s.AbstractStep [AbstractStep.java:222]
>                  Encountered an error executing the step
>   javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress
>      at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.checkTransactionNeeded(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1171) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
>      at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.flush(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1332) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
>      at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor362.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
>      at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55) ~[na:1.7.0]
>      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:618) ~[na:2.6 (01-06-2014)]
>      at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:334) ~[spring-orm-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
>      at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy172.flush(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
>      at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor362.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
>      at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55) ~[na:1.7.0]
>      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:618) ~[na:2.6 (01-06-2014)]
>      at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:257) ~[spring-orm-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
>      at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy172.flush(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
>      at com.nucleus.collection.framework.processes.tasklet.CaseStampingTasklet.execute(CaseStampingTasklet.java:147) ~[collection-framework-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
>      at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:386) ~[spring-batch-core-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:na]
>      at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:133) ~[spring-tx-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
>      at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:264) ~[spring-batch-core-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:na]
>      at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:76) ~[spring-batch-core-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:na]
>      at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:367) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:na]
>      at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:214) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:na]
>      at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:143)

Comment: can you share your spring configuration ?

Comment: Just let me know in case, any specific parameter you want to see in spring configuration file